# Golang: Router config in json file

Tags: json, go

I want to put my router config in an extern json config file like so:

```
{
  "routes": [
    {
      "name": "Index",
      "method": "GET",
      "pattern": "/",
      "handler": "Index"
    },
    {
      "name": "CountsIndex",
      "method": "GET",
      "pattern": "/counts",
      "handler": "CountsIndex"
    }
  ]
}
```

My related struct looks like so:

```
type Route struct {
    Name        string      `json:"name"`
    Method      string      `json:"method"`
    Pattern     string      `json:"pattern"`
    HandlerFunc http.HandlerFunc    `json:"handler"`
}

type Routes []Route
```

The Problem is the handlerFunc. When I get the config it will be a string but how to make it a go value? Can I cast it somehow?

Following error occures:

> json: cannot unmarshal string into Go value of type http.HandlerFunc

Thanks

Comment: You need to be careful here: taking this out of your source code means that you have the potential for what's in your JSON file to not exist in your code, and so you have to test carefully (e.g. iterate over the routes.Handler field and call each one). Is there a reason that you need to have this in a JSON file instead of (say) a `routes.go` that achieves the same result? Does your service run into the scenario where you need to add routes without recompiling?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The simplest solution is to have a string instead of the http.HandlerFunc as type, and define a map with the functions.

```
var functions = map[string]interface{}{
    "func1": func1,
}
```

then after unmarshalling your json you can assign the handler using the handlername of each route

Comment: I tried: var handlers = map[string]http.HandlerFunc {
 "index": Index,
 "countsIndex": CountsIndex,
} but when I assign it I get this error: cannot use route.HandlerFunc (type http.HandlerFunc) as type string in map index

Comment: Ok, I made the handler a string in the struct and then it works. But now I have to add handlers everytime I extend the config, hmm..

Comment: unfortunately in go you can't enumerate all the functions declared in a package, this should have solved the problem to add every time the handler to the map

Comment: Small change to this to make it work for me:

var functions = map[string]http.HandlerFunc

Answer (score 2):

The problem is, that not every data could be marshaled to json (or unmarshaled). http.HandlerFunc is not a function (https://golang.org/pkg/net/http/#HandlerFunc). You cannot put it directly - but you can change handler to string and on the place when you trying to call it obtain HandlerFunc from reflect (a quite complicated) or from prepared map[string]HandlerFunc.

Comment: Thanks, but can you give an example please?

Comment: Sorry, I made a mistake - I though, that is possible to recognize all the functions from module. It is not possible - only I could is find method and execute method from object or type. That means reflect could be use only if all methods would be a method of same object.